# Why are there two directory separator chars?

Tags: c#, .net

In the `Path` class, there are two fields for directory separator chars, `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` and `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`. I know it's not .NET specific but OS dependent but I don't understand why there are two such characters instead of one.

For example there is only one `Path.VolumeSeparatorChar`.

Comment: On windows for example, '\' is the standard separator between directories, but the OS will accept '/' so I imagine that's the motivation behind it.

Comment: _VolumeSeparatorChar_ . The value of this field is a colon (:) on Windows and Macintosh, and a slash (/) on UNIX operating systems. This is most useful for parsing paths such as "c:\windows" or "MacVolume:System Folder".

Answer (score 6):

> The value of this field is a backslash ('\') on UNIX, and a slash ('/') on Windows and Macintosh operating systems.

From MSDN [system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx)

As for [Path.VolumeSeparatorChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.volumeseparatorchar(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> The value of this field is a colon (:) on Windows and Macintosh, and a
>   slash (/) on UNIX operating systems. This is most useful for parsing
>   paths such as "c:\windows" or "MacVolume:System Folder".

However note that on UNIX there is no volume separator as devices are [mounted](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) on the filesystem at a mount point, which is a directory. So one really accesses files with directory separators, therefore causing no ambiguity.

Comment: This does not explain why we have DirectorySeparatorChar in addition to AltDirectorySeparatorChar. In fact, the only difference from their MSDN descriptions is that [the second uses the adjective "alternate"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar?view=netcore-3.1), [while the first doesn't](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Your statement is correct. The answer is the two are equivalent. OP compares this difference with the uniqueness of `Path.VolumeSeparatorChar`. First of all: why does Windows even support the forward slash when its default is the backslash? For Unix file path compatibility (Check MSDN examples, which hint to that, and that reason only). Windows does not use 2 volume separators because Unix works differently causing no ambiguity. So what about Path separator? Windows can not implement an alt for Unix compatibility here... because : (colon) is already used as its Volume Separator.

Comment: Baffour's comment, which I support, is the only motivation also mentioned in MSDN and the only use case reason I have encountered  in my career